# Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker - content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents Problem

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, android-10.0, filepicker

I am using Xamarin.Plugin.FilePicker (version is: 2.1.41). It gives me like this path in android 10 devices:
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3025 or
content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:14

I am trying to get real file path with this way:

```
public class StorageFolderPath : IStorageFolderPath
{
    public string SDCardPath(string path)
    {
        Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
            bool isKitKat = Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat;

        if (isKitKat && DocumentsContract.IsDocumentUri(MainActivity.MainContext, uri))
        {
            if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri))
            {
                //...
            }
            else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri))
            {
                string id = DocumentsContract.GetDocumentId(uri);
                Android.Net.Uri contentUri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(
                                        Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), ContentUris.ParseId(uri));
                return getDataColumn(MainActivity.MainContext, contentUri, null, null);
            }
            //...
        }
    }

    public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs)
        {
            ICursor cursor = null;
            String column = "_data";
            String[] projection =
            {
                column
            };

            try
            {
                cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
                {
                    int index = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
                    return cursor.GetString(index);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.Close();
            }
            return null;
        }

    public static bool isDownloadsDocument(Android.Net.Uri uri)
        {
            return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".Equals(uri.Authority);
        }

    public bool DownloadsDocumentControl(string path)
        {
            Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
            return isDownloadsDocument(uri);
        }
}
```

Shared Codes:

```
public async Task UploadFileAsync(UploadRequest upload_request)
{
    string newPath = "";
    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android && 
       (DependencyService.Get<IStorageFolderPath>().ExternalStorageDocumentControl(upload_request.Properties.FilePath) ||
       DependencyService.Get<IStorageFolderPath>().DownloadsDocumentControl(upload_request.Properties.FilePath)))
        newPath = DependencyService.Get<IStorageFolderPath>().SDCardPath(upload_request.Properties.FilePath);
    else
        newPath = upload_request.Properties.FilePath;

    Stream stream = File.OpenRead(newPath);
    //...
}
```

When I do this:
If path is content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:14, app throws this error:

```
{Java.Lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:14"
  at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+StaticMethods.CallStaticLongMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference type, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* args) [0x0006e] in <42748fcc36b74733af2d9940a8f3cc8e>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeInt64Method (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00018] in <42748fcc36b74733af2d9940a8f3cc8e>:0 
  at Android.Content.ContentUris.ParseId (Android.Net.Uri contentUri) [0x00031] in <7d2292394f8c488b97f5bc2a0ac0240d>:0 
  at FileOrbis.Droid.Services.StorageFolderPath.SDCardPath (System.String path) [0x0017c] in C:\Users\Deytek\Desktop\GitWorkspace\FileorbisMobil\FileOrbis\FileOrbis.Android\Services\StorageFolderPath.cs:91 
  at FileOrbis.Services.AllFileUploadService.UploadFileAsync (FileOrbis.Models.RequestModels.UploadRequest upload_request) [0x000ae] in C:\Users\Deytek\Desktop\GitWorkspace\FileorbisMobil\FileOrbis\FileOrbis\Services\AllFileUploadService.cs:69 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.NumberFormatException stack trace ---
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "msf:14"
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:594)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:636)
    at android.content.ContentUris.parseId(ContentUris.java:89)
}
```

(App crashes in this line: (on ContentUris.ParseId(uri))

```
Android.Net.Uri contentUri = ContentUris.WithAppendedId(
                                        Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), ContentUris.ParseId(uri));)
```

If path is content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3025 , app throws this error:

```
{System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/content:/com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3025".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x00177] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:223 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:91 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare)
  at System.IO.File.OpenRead (System.String path) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/external/corefx/src/System.IO.FileSystem/src/System/IO/File.cs:266 
  at FileOrbis.Services.AllFileUploadService.UploadFileAsync (FileOrbis.Models.RequestModels.UploadRequest upload_request) [0x000de] in C:\Users\Deytek\Desktop\GitWorkspace\FileorbisMobil\FileOrbis\FileOrbis\Services\AllFileUploadService.cs:73 }
```

NOTE:

I added to manifest file:

```
<application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
</application>
```

What must I do on Android 10 devices for this problem? (I don't encounter with this problem on all android 10 devices. I encounter on Samsung Galaxy S10 - emulator, Huawei P20 Lite - real phone or Galaxy S20 - real phone)

Comment: Dont try to get a 'real path' from a nice content scheme uri. Use the uri instead.

Comment: `If path is content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3025 , app throws this error:` Of course. That is no file system path but a content scheme. You need to use other tools/code to handle a content scheme uri.

Comment: How can I use uri for get file?

Comment: If you want to read the content of the file then open an input stream and read. For the rest i dont know what you mean with 'get file'.

Comment: I develop Xamarin.Forms app. I do upload operation on shared code.That's way I need to file path. Because I use Stream stream = File.OpenRead(FilePath); How can I use uri on shared code both ios and android without breaking the ios?

Comment: I dont know. I dont program with Xamarin. But you use a stream so i think you can open a stream for an uri too.

Comment: How do you get the file path using FilePicker? You coulld use the `FilePath` of `Plugin.FilePicker` to get it. It gets the correct file path.

Comment: I use like this: `FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();` `string path = fileData.FilePath;` It gets the correct path a lot of devices. But some android 10 devices gets content uri scheme. [As in the references link.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentUris) I think it is security measures for new android os

Comment: It is not real path. For example I have a file on "Internal Storage/Downloads/Test/file.pdf" file picker gives me like that path: `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:14` or I have a file on "Internal Storage/Downloads/file2.pdf" file picker gives me like that path: `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:25`. So it gives uri scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the blackapps said is true. [Already FilePicker plugin has notified that is possible.](https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows#important) But I see it now.

Getting actual path from content scheme is not true way and it is not possible.
That's why I have to write if condition on my code like that:

```
Stream stream = null;
if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.Android && DependencyService.Get<IStorageFolderPath>().DownloadsDocumentControl(newPath))
     stream = DependencyService.Get<IStorageFolderPath>().GetFileFromUri(newPath);
else
     stream = File.OpenRead(newPath);
```

```
public Stream GetFileFromUri(string path)
{
     Android.Net.Uri uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(path);
     var stream = MainActivity.MainContext.ContentResolver.OpenInputStream(uri);
     return stream;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can query the fileName, and then build the path.

- Query the file name:

  ```
  public static string getFileName(Context context, Android.Net.Uri uri)
  {
      ICursor cursor = null;
      string[] projection = {
          MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName
      };

      try
      {
          cursor = context.ContentResolver.Query(uri, projection, null, null,
          null);
          if (cursor != null && cursor.MoveToFirst())
          {
              int index = cursor.GetColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DisplayName);
              return cursor.GetString(index);
          }
      }
      finally
      {
          if (cursor != null)
              if (cursor != null)
              {
                  cursor.Close();
              }
      }
      return null;
  }
  ```

Build the path:

```
            else if (isDownloadsDocument (uri)) {

                string fileName = getFileName(context, uri);
                string filePath = Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory + "/Download/" + fileName;
                return filePath;
            }
```

Comment: This will only work if the file is not in a sub directory inside Downloads.

Comment: @ClassA Do you have any solution for sub directory, i am getting display name of file from sub directory but not getting subdirectory name